# Next Page Navigation

Tags: javascript, macros, imacros

I am trying to navigate through next pageS using js. It's working fine with navigation but the only issue is it's not getting stop when "next" button is not available. Can we stop it if "next >>" is not available Currently It's loop remains infinite :(

```
var clickNext;
clickNext=  headerCode;
clickNext+= "TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:next<SP>»" + "\n";
clickNext+=  "WAIT SECONDS=5"+  "\n"; 
var nextLink = 1;
for(var i=1; i<=99999999; i++)
{ if(nextLink = 1)
iimPlay(clickNext);
if(nextLink === 0)
break;}
```

Comment: i am not expert in JS but you can go through this link it may help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj663505.aspx

Comment: Thank you Adil! Can anyone else help me out with.Please?

Comment: Write down `if (nextLink == 1)` instead of `if(nextLink = 1)`. (But nevertheless your 'nextLink' is always equal to 1.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickNext;
clickNext = headerCode;
clickNext += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:next<SP>»" + "\n";
clickNext += "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n";
var nextLink = 1;

main : {

    for (var i = 1; i <= 99999999; i++) {
        if (nextLink = 1)
            iimPlay(clickNext);
        if (nextLink === 0)
            break main;
    }

}
```

Try this.